# Jsoup parsing (regex)

Tags: java, jsoup

Could you please advise, how I can extract these messages using jsoup:

> resources/audio/songs/73742facb924e6.mp3
>
> Future Is Now
>
> Green Grey

from this code:

```
<div class="playlist-item" 
    id="playlist-item-2" 
    data-song-id="8365" 
     
    onmouseover="javascript: pageUtils.playlistItemSharebar(2);"
    onclick="jwPlayerUtils.playSong(8365, 2, event); _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1091709-7']); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);">
    
    <input type="hidden" id="song-path-8365" value="resources/audio/songs/73742facb924e6.mp3" />
    <input type="hidden" id="song-mode-8365" value="song" />
    <input type="hidden" id="song-name-left-8365" value="Future Is Now" />
    <input type="hidden" id="song-name-right-8365" value="Green Grey" />
    <input type="hidden" id="song-programName-8365" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="song-img-8365" value="resources/img/songs/98x74_DIR/8365.jpg?201702161231" />
```

Here what I have already try:

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).execute().parse();

        Elements elements = document.select(".playlist-item");
        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println("Artist: " + element.select("[id~=^song-name-right-[0-9]+$]").select("[value]"));
            System.out.println("Song: " + element.select("[id~=^song-name-left-[0-9]+$]").select("[value]"));;
            System.out.println("Link: " + element.select("[id~=^song-path-[0-9]+$]").select("[value]"));
        }
```

But the result is full string:

input type="hidden" id="song-path-8365" value="resources/audio/songs/73742facb924e6.mp3" />
input type="hidden" id="song-name-left-8365" value="Future Is Now" />
input type="hidden" id="song-name-right-8365" value="Green Grey" />

I'm sure that there is some other (easier and more correct) way to cope with this, so will appreciate any help

Comment: what do you want to extract ??

Comment: @RamanSahasi, this is regex: "[id~=^song-name-right-[0-9]+$]"

Comment: @thanga, I need to extract "resources/audio/songs/73742facb924e6.mp3, Future Is Now, Green Grey" I wrote it in my massage. I wrote what I need, and from where I need.

Comment: try input .attr("value")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Elements inputs = document.select("input");
for(Element input:inputs){
    System.out.println(input.attr("value"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know that it have to be really easy)